# GitHub - UI allowing non-technical collaborators to edit files

Tags: github

I have a Github  repository that only contains one file - a readme.md. I want to distribute an edit link to several non-tech-savvy collaborators, but without having to explain to them what "commit" and "pull-requests" mean.

When they access the edit link, these collaborators should see a simple text editor and a save button. The text editor should load the current version of readme.md.

When they click Save, a commit+pull request should be generated in the background in my repository.

Is there a way to achieve this with GitHub, GitHub integrations, third-party tools or GitHub APIs? Or, is it possible to do this using a different service (BitBucket, GitLab etc)?

Comment: Atleast in BitBucket there is a feature to edit files on your browser and push the changes to remote. I use it sometimes. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: @AulisRonkainen - but isn't that available to the repo owner and repo members only?

Comment: Yes, you obviously need to create users for them, but they don't have to know how to do commits and all that technical stuff. I don't know how well BitBucket works with GitHub, though.